# Netbeans + Maven + TestNG - How to run test suites from netbeans?

Tags: maven, netbeans, testng

I have tests in the Test Packages of the project.
I also have some suites.xml files in a package inside the Test Packages.

For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="automation_chrome">
    <test name="All tests running in Chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.company.testsuites.LoginTest">
                <methods>
                     <include name="successfulLogin" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>    
</suite>
```

Test case:

```
package com.company.testsuites;

import com.company.generictestssuites.MainTest;
import org.testng.Assert;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest extends MainTest {

    @Test
    public void successfulLogin() throws Exception {
        login("user1@test.com", "123password1");
        Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.getUserLoged(), "Test User 1");
    }
}
```

I can right click the test and run it selecting the "Test File" option.
But when I right click the suite.xml to run the tests it doesn't run the tests.

This is the result:

```
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to fix this to be able to run the tests from Jenkins though Maven.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>chrome.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>firefox.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>iexplorer.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>  
        </plugin>
```

Sadly I couldn't find any complete documentation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by this two changes:

1- In the POM file:

```
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}/chrome.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}/firefox.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}/iexplorer.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
```

2- Move the xml files (the suites) to the default package in the TestPackages.